# How to colorize man-page in Fish shell?

Tags: bash, shell, colors, fish, manpage

The bash solution described [`tmux` man-page search highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10535432/802365) works great in bash but fail when ported in `fish`.

#### Fish config

```
function configure_pager
    # Colored man pages: http://linuxtidbits.wordpress.com/2009/03/23/less-colors-for-man-pages/
    # Less Colors for Man Pages
    set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_mb '\E[01;31m'       # begin blinking
    set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_md '\E[01;38;5;74m'  # begin bold
    set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_me '\E[0m'           # end mode
    set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_se '\E[0m'           # end standout-mode
    set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_so '\E[38;5;016m\E[48;5;220m'    # begin standout-mode - info box
    set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_ue '\E[0m'           # end underline
    set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_us '\E[04;38;5;146m' # begin underline
end
```

#### Rendering in fish

Instead of the color I got the un-interpreted code:
    LS(1)                                                                                                         User Commands                                                                                                         LS(1)

```
\E[01;38;5;74mNAME\E[0m
       ls - list directory contents

\E[01;38;5;74mSYNOPSIS\E[0m
       \E[01;38;5;74mls\E[0m [\E[04;38;5;146mOPTION\E[0m]... [\E[04;38;5;146mFILE\E[0m]...

\E[01;38;5;74mDESCRIPTION\E[0m
       List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).  Sort entries alphabetically if none of \E[01;38;5;74m-cftuvSUX\E[0m nor \E[01;38;5;74m--sort\E[0m is specified.
```

#### Question

This might be due to me using a wrong syntax for string literal variable in `fish`:

```
set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_mb '\E[01;31m'       # begin blinking
```

original `bash` is:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[01;31m'       # begin blinking
```

**What is the correct syntax for color coding in fish?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing in the bash version is [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting). This makes bash interpret the sequence before setting it to the variable. So LESS_TERMCAP_mb doesn't contain the literal string "\E[01;31m", but the sequence specified by that - in particular, the "\E" is the escape character.

In fish, what you want to do is specify the escape sequence outside of quotes - see [the section on quotes in the fish documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#quotes):

```
set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_mb \e'[01;31m'
```

and so on.

#### Preview

[image: fish man page highlight configuration]

Comment: It's also possible to abuse `printf`, e.g. `set -gx LESS_TERMCAP_mb (printf "\e[01;31m")`.